# Devise: Change any users password as admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So this seems simple enough, I have a controller action that looks like this:

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
...
def update_password
  @user = User.find(params[:user][:id])
  @user.password = params[:user][:password]
  if @user.save!
    Notifier.admin_password_change(@user).deliver
    flash[:success] = "Password Changed!"
    redirect_to edit_admin_user_path(@user)
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
end
```

and it never seems to work. Do I need to something more advanced here? Here's what I see in the rails console:

```
Started PUT "/admin/users/update_password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-15 10:01:50 -0600
Processing by Admin::UsersController#update_password as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ipedx2MJDZTQct6I4FUObrzDpMNl3pQWNVr9Ez7bDVc=", "user"=>{"id"=>"226", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change Password"}
  (6.8ms)  ALTER SESSION SET EDITION = EPACT_REDESIGN
  User Load (8.4ms)  SELECT "CRED_APP_USERS".* FROM "CRED_APP_USERS" WHERE "CRED_APP_USERS"."ID_NUMBER" = 10040 AND ROWNUM <= 1
  CodeModel Load (9.1ms)  SELECT "CRED_CODES".* FROM "CRED_CODES" WHERE (table_name = 'CRED_VEHICLES' OR table_name = 'CRED_FLEET')
  User Load (3.6ms)  SELECT "CRED_APP_USERS".* FROM "CRED_APP_USERS" WHERE "CRED_APP_USERS"."ID_NUMBER" = :a1 AND ROWNUM <= 1  [["id_number", "226"]]
  (3.3ms)  UPDATE "CRED_APP_USERS" SET "ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD" = 'ENCRYPTED PASSWORD STRING', "MODIFY_DT" = TO_DATE('2013-07-15 16:01:50','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') WHERE "CRED_APP_USERS"."ID_NUMBER" = 226
 Rendered notifier/admin_password_change.erb (0.1ms)

Sent mail to random@person.com (22ms)
...
```

What am I doing wrong here? The email prints out in the console, and the `:success` flash appears at the top of the screen, but the password hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

Can't say I understand why, but I needed to set a `password_reset_token`, and then it worked. Here's what the method looks like now:

```
def update_password
  @user = User.find(params[:user][:id])
  @user.reset_password_token = 'temp'
  @user.save!
  if @user.reset_password!(params[:user][:password], params[:user][:password_confirmation])
    Notifier.admin_password_change(@user).deliver
    flash[:success] = "Password Changed!"
    redirect_to edit_admin_user_path(@user)
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

The token get's blown away when the `reset_password!` method runs. I couldn't find anything in the docs that alluded to needing a `reset_password_token`, but it seems to be required. I wouldn't say this code is pretty, but the solution works. If someone else comes up with something better, I'll change my answer.